# Regex search and replace across multiple files

Tags: php, regex, perl, notepad++

I need to refactor some code across multiple php files stored in multiple folders.

I need to replace code instances like:

```
 trim(ucfirst($userinfo['first_name'])).' '.trim(ucfirst($userinfo['last_name']))
```

With text (in place, within those files) as:

```
 formatUserName($userinfo['first_name'],$userinfo['last_name'])
```

Note that the $ variable name will be different, but everything else will be the same*.

I am on a Windows machine, but have php and perl installed - would prefer to use that instead of sed.

I have Notepad++, but not sure if that can handle such search and replacement operations.

*There are variations of this line in our code, which once I have an understanding of how to build the proper regex, I'll attempt on my own.

Comment: How many files are we talking about? If it's within reason, you could simply use an editor that lets you create a project (to which you add all files) and run a find-and-replace on all files in the project (I use PSPad). Then do a find on the name variables to check you've updated all instances of this problem.

Comment: @Will - this is a programming question - I'm trying to determine the appropriate regex to use.

Comment: This isn't about solving a specific programming problem you are facing, its about replacing text in multiple files, the tools that can be used to accomplish this, and how to use them to perform the replacement.  Not on topic, and I don't want it to remain open so that it can be used as an example for other questions that aren't a good fit for StackOverflow.  Also, you've got an answer; there isn't  a need to keep it open.

Comment: Thank you Will for taking the time to respond - I appreciate the clarification. I wanted to write a perl/php/sed 'program', but the simplest proposed solution was to use an editor. I dont think my question is any different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477434/regex-to-find-replace-argument-pattern-in-a-function-call-across-all-files . However, I trust and respect your call, so we can end the matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Notepad++ version 6.0, you can do:

find what : `trim\(ucfirst\((\$\w+\['first_name'\])\)\)\.' '\.trim\(ucfirst\((\$\w+\['last_name'\])\)\)`

replace with:  `formatUserName\(\1,\2\)`

Comment: I think it needs to be formatUserName(\1,\2)

Comment: It is working awesomely...! :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is about how to handle meta characters. Here's one way to do it.

```
my $find    = q|trim(ucfirst($userinfo['first_name'])).' '.trim(ucfirst($userinfo['last_name']))|;
my $replace = q|formatUserName($userinfo['first_name'],$userinfo['last_name'])|;

while (<>) {
    s/\Q$find\E/$replace/g;
}
```

`\Q ... \E` will cause the regex to match what is inside it literally, although variables are still interpolated.

Comment: The question said the variable name is different.

Comment: @daxim The question said a lot of things. I answered the part about meta characters.

Comment: yeah, the variable name $userinfo will be $admininfo, $insinfo, etc... It will be the same between the 'first_name' and 'last_name' though.

Comment: Oh the serial downvoter strikes again...

Answer (score 0):

Untested (no Windows shell available):

```
perl -i.bak -lpe"BEGIN { $varname = qr/\$[a-z]+/; } s/trim\(ucfirst\(($varname)\['first_name'\]\)\)\.' '\.trim\(ucfirst\(\1\[\'last_name'\]\)\)/formatUserName($1['first_name'],$1['last_name'])/;" file1.php file2.php file3.php …
```

Note the `\1` backref in the match part and the `$1` capture buffers in the subst part.

Comment: Windows shell won't automatically glob a parameter for you. Also WIndows Perl won't let you do in-place editing without a backup file: you need `-i.bak` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

***Script:***

```
$_ = 'trim(ucfirst($userinfo[\'first_name\'])).\' \'.trim(ucfirst($userinfo[\'last_name\']))';
s/^trim\(ucfirst\((\$[^\)]+)\)\)\.'\s+'\.trim\(ucfirst\((\$[^\)]+)\)\)$/formatUserName($1,$2)/; 
print $_;
```

***Output:***

```
formatUserName($userinfo['first_name'],$userinfo['last_name'])
```

Test link: http://ideone.com/4e0Bf

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the best way is to use the [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) module to populate `@ARGV` and then simply do the substitutions within a `while (<>)` loop.

This program show the idea, but I haven't tested the regular expression so be careful. A backup copy of the files will be saved as `*.php.bak`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

our @ARGV = ();

find sub {
  push @ARGV, $File::Find::name if /\.php$/;
}, 'C:\path\to\tree\root';

$^I = '.bak';

while (<>) {
  s<\Qtrim(ucfirst(\E\$(\w+)\Q['first_name'])).' '.trim(ucfirst(\E\$\1\Q['last_name']))\E>
   <formatUserName(\$$1['first_name'],\$$1['last_name'])>g;
  print;
}
```